# if statement with "2 word" strings

Tags: c++, string, if-statement

What am I doing wrong?
I want this expression to be displayed/work after my input: cout << "Please enter your Agent ID.";
But it would not register the whole word of my input: **log in** when I type it with space. If it was a word without space it would register it and do the if statement properly if the condition is met.

So I don't know what I am doing wrong.

Here's the Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
int main()
{
    using namespace std;
    string input1;
    cout << "Welcome to AgentOS" << endl;
    cout << "To log in, please type \"log in\" " << endl;
    cin >> input1;
    
    if (getline(cin, input1) && input1 == "log in")
    {
        cout << "Please enter your Agent ID." << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Instead of display "Please enter your Agent ID", it would just simply return to 0 after I type in *log in*.

P.S. I am sorry I am still a beginner.

Comment: Explanation of duplicate: `cin >> input1;` stops reading the first time it encounters a space. It looks like you could just drop that line entirely because you immediately `getline`, which will read an entire line at a time.

Comment: @NathanPierson AH, oh my Lord! It was so simple, 
Thank you!